# linear gradient in Svelte each loop not working

Tags: svelte, diagram, linear-gradients, chord

I have created a linearGradient for an SVG chord diagram using Svelte. Each chord should have its own gradient assigned from among 7 colors, for a total of 21 separate gradients assigned to 21 paths. Inspecting the SVG element, I can see the Svelte #each loop correctly assigns the color stops inside the linearGradient. However, the paths are not getting the updated linearGradient information. I have tried approaches including using index to update the reference each time, but none seem to work. I have tried my best to phrase this question correctly according to Stackoverflow. Any thoughts are much appreciated!

```
    {#each ribbons as ribbon, i}
<!-- ribbons with linear gradients -->
<defs>
  <linearGradient id={"gradient"} gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
    <stop offset="5%" stop-color={`${colors[ribbon.source.index]}`} />
    <stop offset="95%" stop-color={`${colors[ribbon.target.index]}`} />
  </linearGradient>
</defs>
<path
  d={ribbon.path}
  fill={"url('#gradient')"}
  fill-opacity={0.7}
>
</path>
```

{/each}

Comment: They all show the first (or last) gradient don't they ?

Comment: Thanks Stephane yes they all get the first gradient.

Answer (score 0):

Likely they are all using the same gradient because you are effectively rendering this

```html
<defs>
  <linearGradient id="gradient">...</linearGradient>
</defs>
<path fill="url(#gradient)">...</path>
<defs>
  <linearGradient id="gradient">...</linearGradient>
</defs>
<path fill="url('#gradient')">...</path>
```

Note that **all** gradients use the same id and **all** paths point to the same id as well. Since ids are supposed to be unique the browser will simply ignore the second definition when looking up the id in `url(#gradient)`.

You can solve this by making the ids unique, maybe use the index or other unique identifier like the actual chord?

```html
<linearGradient="gradient-{i}">
<path fill="url('#gradient-{i}')">
```

Comment: Thanks again Stephane I did try something like this but maybe have the syntax wrong. I believe that a template literal is required but this doesn't seem to work:       fill={"url('#gradient-`${i}`')"}

I can see in the inspector the defs are updating the color stops, but the fill reference is not updated.

Comment: you shouldn't need the template literal `$`, you also don't need the outside curly braces, just `fill="url('#gradient-{0}')"` is enough (also when defining the id for the gradient)

Comment: Works! Fantastic. Really appreciate it, unfortunate that I can't upvote due to my lack of interactions here. So I guess the lesson is that Svelte's curly brace expressions obviate the need for a template literal, and be careful about the ID referencing.